# La différence entre « sentir » et « se sentir »

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes-pronominaux

J'ai vu les deux phrases suivantes, et je me demande pourquoi dans la première phrase, on utilise « sentir » et dans l'autre, on utilise « se sentir »:

> 1 - J’aimerais partager ce que je sens.
>
> 2 - J’aimerais partager comment je me sens.

Comment: Peux-tu dire dans quel(s) contexte(s) tu as lu/entendu ces deux phrases ? Pour ma part je ne n’emploierais ni l'une ni l'autre. Dans la première j'emploierais le verbe « ressentir » et la deuxième je ne suis pas sûre de la comprendre.

Comment: La consultation du [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sentir) pourrait t'apporter un premier éclairage sur la différence entre « sentir » et « se sentir ».

Answer (score 5):

> J’aimerais partager ce que *je sens*.

Dans cette phrase, *sentir* est l'action du sens olfactif ou tactile, c'est à dire ce que le *je* perçois des odeurs extérieures à son corps ou ce qui touche son corps.

> J’aimerais partager comment *je me sens*.

*Se sentir* permet aux émotions de connaître quel est, ou quels sont les sens que le *je* perçoit à l'intérieur de sa peau, il est  alors question de niveau de sensibilité.

À moins qu'il y ait un contexte particulier dans votre question, *comment je me sens* est ici compris comme *quelles sont les émotions que je ressens* ou *J’aimerais partager mon état affectif* (ce qui m'affecte en ce moment... en bien ou en mal).

Sans aucun contexte, la tournure des phrases proposées est malhabile et à éviter, car on partage un objet, une idée voire une émotion, mais pas une perception qui est liée au corps par définition impartageable.

> J'aimerais faire connaître/percevoir/découvrir/apprécier... ce que je perçois.
>
> J'aimerais faire ressentir/connaître/aimer/.. ce que je ressens.

... sont des phrases plus acceptables.

Comment: Cette réponse est une tentative d'explication des verbes « sentir » et « se sentir » qui ne tient pas compte des phrases dans lesquelles ils sont employés.  Je ne comprends pas l'utilisation du verbe « partager » en relation avec une sensation olfactive ou tactile. Et quant à « je me sens » ça n'exprime pas un état affectif mais physique et comment peut-on le partager ?

Comment: À mon sens, aucune des deux phrases n'est correcte. Les deux semblent vouloir dire: "J'aimerais que vous ressentiez ce que je ressens".

Comment: @Laure Étrange : « Je sens le parfum des roses, je sens tes lèvres sur ma peau » n'est-il pas lié au perceptions tactiles ou olfactives, donc, « j'aimerais partager ... » *ce plaisir, cette jouissance* (jouie-sens). C'est la façon dont je lis cette phrase ex nihilo, et donc la réponse pour l'utilisation de « Je sens ». « Je me sens mal, je me sens idéalement bien » sont deux expressions qui relèvent de l'affectif (Psychol : Qui concerne les états de plaisir ou de douleur - le Robert) et donc une réponse pour la seconde question... et que fait-on au moment des fêtes sinon partager son plaisir ?

Comment: @Iside Si l'on accepte le sens « Partager qqch avec qqn : lui en donner une partie - le Robert » que faites vous du partage de la douleur dans les deuils, ou de la joie quand il y le bonheur en excès ? « Je suis tellement heureux que je voudrais que tout le monde soit comme moi ! ». La phrase est certes inconfortable, mais elle ne me semble pas incorrecte.

Comment: @cl-r Comme tu dis c'est le **plaisir** qu'on peut partager,  et non pas  l'objet qu'on sent ou qu'on touche. C'est pour ça que dire « J’aimerais partager ce que je sens.  » ne veut rien dire et on devrait dire  « J’aimerais partager ce que je ressens ».

Comment: @Laure La phrase brute n'est pas très lisible, mais dans un contexte : « Ah, si mon ami était là, j'aimerais *partager* avec lui ce que sens dans ce jardin ». J'ai complété ma réponse pour tenir compte de vos commentaires.

Comment: @cl-r Je suis bien d'accord avec le partage de la douleur, de la joie, du plaisir. C'est bien pour cela que "J'aimerais partager ce que je ressens" me semble correct. En utilisant le verbe ressentir, il n'y a aucune ambiguïté.

Comment: @cl-r C'est bien pour ça que la question est très mal posée et que j'avais demandé un complément d'explication à la personne qui l'a posée.

Answer (score 1):

Le verbe sentir a plusieurs sens possibles. Le parfum sent bon. Je sens une odeur de gaz. Je sens de l'air froid qui passe sous cette porte. Je sens que la situation va se gâter. Je ne peux pas la sentir (familier pour je la déteste).

Le verbe se sentir exprime un état physique ou état d'âme. Je me sens très bien. Elle se sent mal.

Answer (score 1):

« Sentir » c'est recevoir une impression par l'un de ses sens. Quand on dit « ce que je sens » hors contexte, *ce que* représente l'objet qui procure la sensation olfactive ou tactile (fleur, gaz, vent qui caresse la peau, etc.).
Donc dire :

> J’aimerais partager ce que je sens.

veut dire qu'on veut partager cet objet pour que l'autre éprouve la même sensation. La phrase est grammaticalement correcte mais ce n'est pas clair et il vaudrait mieux dire quelque chose comme :

> J’aimerais partager cette fleur pour que tu la sentes aussi.

Si c'est la sensation qu'on veut partager, c'est à dire ce qui se passe dans le corps quand on reçoit l'impression, alors il faut employer le verbe *ressentir* :

> J’aimerais partager ce que je ressens.

Le verbe *partager* est transitif et ne peut pas se construire avec « comment ». Et pour moi la phrase 
  <del>J’aimerais partager comment je me sens.</del> <sup>1</sup>

n'est pas compréhensible. Il faudrait dire :

> J'aimerais t'expliquer comment je me sens.

Ou alors revenir à :

> J’aimerais partager ce que je ressens.

« Se sentir », est un verbe pronominal et s'emploie toujours suivi :

- soit d'un verbe à l'infinitif pour exprimer un changement d'action :

  > Je me sens revivre.
- soit d'un adjectif pour exprimer la qualité de ce qui est ressenti :

  > Je me sens mal.
  >   Je me sens fatigué.
  >   Je me sens libéré de tous mes soucis.
- soit plus rarement d'un nom, surtout dans des expressions :

  > Je me sens d'humeur à faire la fête.
  >   Je ne me sens pas le courage de tout faire tout seul.

« Comment » ne s'emploie en relation avec le verbe *se sentir* que dans la question pour prendre la place du mot inconnu qu'on attend dans la réponse :

> - Comment te sens-tu ?
>     Tu te sens comment ?
> - Je me sens bien/mal/lessivé/au comble du bonheur...

ou après les verbes amenant demandant de compléter un déficit d'information tels que dire, expliquer, etc. :

> - Je vais te dire comment je me sens.

ce qui n'est pas le cas du verbe partager qui amène un complément d'objet qui peut être une proposition,  « ce que je ressens » dans la phrase 2 de la question.

---

<sup>1</sup> Cette phrase sent la mauvaise traduction de la construction anglaise :  *share how*.

<sup>2</sup> Sauf dans l'expression impersonnelle *Ça se sent* qui veut « ça se comprend » / « Ça se perçoit / « Ça se devine »

Answer (score 1):

Effectivement la phrase 1 est correcte, mais pas la seconde "J’aimerais partager comment je me sens". Si vous souhaitez exprimer votre désir de partager les détails de ce que vous ressentez, vous pouvez dire

J’aimerais partager (avec vous, si vous faites la cour) mes sentiments les plus profonds et vous transmettre la manière dont je vis la situation présente.

Comment: +1 pour trouver l’astuce pour garder le concept génial de «partager» en parlant de nos sentiments/de comment nous nous sentons. En plus, moi je trouve que «partager mes sensations» (et même «mes sentiments») marcherait aussi pour la phrase 1 (ce que je sens) car il y a plusieurs définitions pour SENTIR (NON-pronominal) qui parlent de «AVOIR une sensation» (et même de «AVOIR un sentiment» (et pas seulement de les percevoir/recevoir d’un objet par l'un de nos sens) et de cet «AVOIR» on peut bien parler de partager ce que j’AI comme sensation/sentiment=partager mes sensations/sentiments, non?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is the consequence of a question tagged as duplicate but asked by someone whose natural language is English (@ND523); there seems to be no problem in repeating that answer here as it might provide a speaker of English with valuable precisions.

**The duplicate question, or rather a variant of the question asked above**

When translating sentences containing the phrase “you make me feel”, the translator comes up with sentences with either « tu me fais me sentir » or « tu me fais sentir ».

Why is « sentir » reflexive in some sentences (J’aime le façon que tu me fais me sentir bien) but not in others (Tu me fais sentir comme un roi)? What is the grammatical rule that dictates it?

**Answer**

There is no grammatical rule involved and this is plainly a matter of meaning. You are dealing with two verbs, each with its meaning, one of the type called "pronominal" (se sentir) and the other "a plain transitive verb" (sentir quelque chose ou quelqu'un).

I

"se sentir" means "to feel oneself"

example: I felt myself being pulled down towards the bottom of the river.

Cela se traduit par "Je me sentais tiré vers le fond de la rivière."

dictionary: Avoir conscience de l'état physique ou moral dans lequel on se trouve

II

"sentir quelque chose ou quelqu'un" has two main meanings, one is literal, the other figurative.

example:

-literal- I could smell flowers and the scent of freshly cut grass.

This is translated as "Je sentais des fleurs et et l'odeur de l'herbe qui venait d'être coupée.".

meaning (a): to smell

-figurative- The rider felt the horse was getting tired and slowed down its pace to a trot.

A translation of this is "Le cavalier sentit que le cheval était fatigué et le mis au trot.".

meaning (b): to feel

III

In the first case (tu me fais me sentir) the verb is the pronominal verb; the translation is "you make me feel" and in English you do not use a pronominal form (you make me feel myself).

For instance "He made me feel forlorn." will be in French "Il me faisait me sentir délaissé(e).".

Another example: They make her feel as if she were the worse possible candidate for the post.

A translation of that could be "Ils la font se sentir comme si elle était la pire des candidates pour le poste.

It is very interesting here to remark the different pronoun used if the other verb is found; there is next an example of that.

The new clothes she bought make her feel the curves of her body, or so says she.

The translation is now "D'après elle, les nouveaux vêtements qu'elle a achetés lui font sentir les courbes de son corps."

"se sentir les courbes" would not be correct in this sentence.

dictionary: Percevoir, éprouver une sensation physique qui renseigne sur l'état de l'organisme ou sur le milieu extérieur

example: They make you feel much less the burning of the sun's rays.

A translation of that could be "Ils vous font sentir beaucoup moins la brulure des rayons du soleil.

In the second case you are dealing with the figurative verb, in "II".

example: The festivities made her feel a certain emptiness in her soul, gave her a sense of her being useless.

In French we have "Les réjouissances lui faisait ressentir une certaine absence d'âme, lui donnait une impression d'être inutile.

For this latter translation "ressentir" is idiomatic whereas "sentir" is not quite correct but the idea is close and can be understood.

One must say that there is not too great a difference between "Avoir conscience de l'état physique ou moral dans lequel on se trouve" and "Percevoir, éprouver une sensation physique qui renseigne sur l'état de l'organisme ou sur le milieu extérieur" but it is important enough to compel one to discriminate between the two.